# Rails Reservation System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a reservation system where users can search for an open reservation. The `:on` scope filters the reservations that are present on a given day and time and I create an array of `reserved_table_ids`. If there are reservations on the selected day/time, `@reserved_tables` and `@open_tables` contain the correct table ids. However, if there aren't any reservations on a selected day/time, `reserved_table_ids` is null and `@reserved_tables` and `@open_tables` are empty. Any ideas on how to shovel all table_ids into `@open_tables` if `reserved_table_ids` is null? Or are there other approaches I should consider? (Rails 5.0.1)

Models:

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :table, optional: true

  scope :on, -> (day, time) { where('date = ? AND starts_at <= ? AND ends_at > ?', day, time, time)}
end

class Table < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :users, through: :reservations

  def self.free_on(day, time)
    reserved_table_ids = Reservation.on(day, time).pluck('DISTINCT table_id')
    where.not(id: reserved_table_ids)
  end

  def self.reserved_on(day, time)
    reserved_table_ids = Reservation.on(day, time).pluck('DISTINCT table_id')
    where(id: reserved_table_ids)
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :tables, through: :reservations
end
```

Controller:

```
class TablesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @reserved_tables = Table.reserved_on(params[:day], params[:time])
    @open_tables = Table.free_on(params[:day], params[:time])
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_tag(tables_path, :method => "get", id: "table-search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :day, params[:day], class:"datepicker", placeholder: "Select Day" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :time, params[:time], class:"timepicker", placeholder: "Select Time" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is an issue when reserved_table_ids is empty. Could you try adding an extra conditional?

```
def self.free_on(day, time)
  reserved_table_ids = Reservation.on(day, time).pluck('DISTINCT table_id')
  if reserved_table_ids
    where.not(id: reserved_table_ids)
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Or using a ternary:

```
def self.free_on(day, time)
  reserved_table_ids = Reservation.on(day, time).pluck('DISTINCT table_id')
  reserved_table_ids ? where.not(id: reserved_table_ids) : all
end
```

Comment: I was thinking conditional too but I like your ternary solution because it is cleaner. Thanks!